# Why don't Java LinkedHashMaps have an insert() method?

Tags: java

By `insert()`, I mean `insertBefore(key)` or `insertAfter(key)`.

As far as I can make out, inserting a key in the middle of the map can only be achieved by creating a new map and copying across the existing keys and the new key in the correct order.

Considering that LinkedHashMaps are based on double-linked lists, it would have been trivial to implement `insertBefore(key)` or `insertAfter(key)`.

Am I missing something here?

**Update**
Thanks to everyone who pointed out the the above methods would break the contract of maintaining insertion order.

So let me rephrase the question: does anyone know of a class that would let me do this?

I looked at `SortedMap` (and its derivatives, including `NavigableMap`) but I don't want the map to be explicitly sorted. Think of a `nodeList` in the browser DOM. I just need to be able to insert elements (in this case KV pairs) in any arbitrary order.

Thanks

Comment: If you have such a need, go on, implement it and use it for your own benefit.

Comment: @Boris - I do have such a need, and if I can't find an implementation, I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an ordered map, it is intended that you use a NavigableMap

Comment: In that case, the simplest thing to do would be to maintain a Map and a List. The Map has the lookup and the List has the order you desire.  It is fairly common to need the features of two collections at once, and this is usually achieved by wrapping two collections. (Or just using two as is)

Answer (score 3):

Because `Map` doesn't have `insert()` or `insertFirst()` or `insertAfter()` methods. Having said that, it is no more trivial thing to do. May be a class which doesn't belong to this hierarchy could do that.

Comment: That's because a general Map is not ordered, and so those methods would make no sense.

Comment: @David: Thats why I said, a class that doesn't belong to this hierarchy can do that easily. BTW, I was looking for similar thing if Guava, if they have it. But it seems that they don't. Disclaimer, I never worked with Guava extensively.

Answer (score 3):

LinkedHashMap maintains either **access-order** or **insertion-order**. It doesn't make sense to define `insertBefore(key)` or `insertAfter(key)` I think.

Comment: It maintains insertion order, so I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).

Hence this part of the contract of the class can only be maintained, if you have zero degrees of freedom as to where an element is inserted.  Inserting before an(y) existing element clearly violates this part of the contract, so such an `insert` method would not make any sense.

(The only version that would be legal would be an `insertAfter(key)` where `key` was always the last entry in the map.  And lo, that's exactly what `put(key)` does already.)